# Generating urls in django

Tags: django, django-urls

hey guys i am beginner in django
I want to generate url in django like this

```
http://something.com/searchpage/?page=12&color=red
```

currently in use this type of url

```
url(r'^searchpage/(?P<page>\d+)/(?P<color>\w+)$','home_product.views.search'),
```

plz help me

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a GET request: just point your url to

```
url(r'^searchpage/$, 'home_product.views.search'),
```

and pull up the query terms from the `request.GET` directory in your `views.py`:

```
def search(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    color = request.GET.get('color')
    ...
```

(Using `GET.get`, you will set missing values to `None`).

Comment: i want to generate url like this    something.com/searchpage/?page=12&color=red

Comment: What do you mean by "generate url"? From within a template or as a redirect? Please make your question clearer.